# POSIX API for standard clipbaord access/functions?

Tags: unix, posix

Is there an api within the POSIX UNIX API standard for access to clipboard, like fetching current pasted item, changing current pasted item etc?

Also what I see is there does not seem to be any community or atleast that I can find where I might find more resources and posts about people developing stuff using the POSIX APIs (I know its such a niche and probably there aren't many developers working on them everyday to churn out OSes like mcdonalds burgers). Could someone point me to an appropriate place if they know exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What's a "clipboard"? Isn't it a concept specific to GUIs? POSIX doesn't do GUIs.
2. For the POSIX API, go to [The Open Group Base Specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), volume *System Interfaces*.

POSIX describes the interfaces which the operating system exposes to application programs. It is a tool for *application* developers, not for operating system developers.

Comment: Alright. But isn’t there a standard for handling clipboards across all unix os? Because to me clipboard functionality seems to be an interface that an os would expose to application programs

Comment: No operating system has any notion of a "clipboard". Clipboards are implemented by graphical user interfaces. If by "Unix OS" you mean the X Window System (which is also available on Windows and OpenVMS) there are indeed such rules, defined by the [Inter-Client Communication Conventions Manual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-Client_Communication_Conventions_Manual) (ICCCM). You don't want to read that. You want to read the documentation of the specific toolkit used by your application, be it [GTK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B), [KDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE), Tk etc.

Comment: that was quite helpful. Thanks